# Expression Tree copying object

Tags: c#, tree, expression

Trying to create an expression tree to do an object mapper type thing.

```
Type ts = typeof(Source);
Type td = typeof(Dest);

ParameterExpression val = Expression.Parameter(ts);
ParameterExpression ret = Expression.Parameter(td);

PropertyInfo[] propsS = ts.GetProperties();
PropertyInfo[] propsD = td.GetProperties();

List<Expression> lst = new List<Expression>();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propsS)
{
    PropertyInfo piD = propsD.Where(x => x.Name == pi.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (piD != null)
    {
        MethodInfo ge = pi.GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo se = piD.GetSetMethod();
        var v1 = Expression.Call(val, ge);
        var v2 = Expression.Call(ret, se, v1);
        lst.Add(v2);
    }
}

lst.Add(Expression.Return(Expression.Label(td), ret));

BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
        new[] { ret },
        lst.ToArray()
    );

//Func<Source, Dest> v = Expression.Lambda<Func<Source, Dest>>(block, val).Compile();
var v = Expression.Lambda(block, val);
```

So that's what I have now... its very close, but don't see what I'm missing...

v comes out to:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`1[ConsoleApplication2.Source]>(ConsoleApplication2.Source $var1) {
    .Block(ConsoleApplication2.Dest $var2) {
        .Call $var2.set_S1(.Call $var1.get_S1());
        .Call $var2.set_S2(.Call $var1.get_S2());
        .Call $var2.set_I1(.Call $var1.get_I1());
        .Call $var2.set_I2(.Call $var1.get_I2());
        .Call $var2.set_S3(.Call $var1.get_S3());
        .Call $var2.set_S4(.Call $var1.get_S4());
        .Call $var2.set_S5(.Call $var1.get_S5());
        .Return #Label1 { $var2 }
    }
}
```

1. Do I need to new up $var2 somewhere?
2. Is there a better way to do the assigns?
3. The lambda doesn't seem to see the return value...
4. Do I need to do the block? or is there a better way?

Comment: Either the returned lambda needs to be `Action<Source, Dest>` so that you're passing two objects, or `Dest` needs to be created, and use `Func<Source,Dest>`. You're currently defining a local variable for `var2`, but `var2` is never constructed (or passed in)

Comment: @Rob -- I want the Func<Source, Dest> result, but the compiler thinks its still an Action even though I have a return... how do I need to modify the code to new up $var2 inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
Type sourceType = typeof(Source);
ParameterExpression source = Expression.Parameter(sourceType);

var createModel = Expression.New(typeof(Dest));
var bindings = new List<MemberAssignment>();
foreach (var prop in sourceType.GetProperties())
{
    var v1 = Expression.Call(source, prop.GetGetMethod());
    var destinationProperty = typeof(Dest).GetProperty(prop.Name);

    bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(destinationProperty, v1));
}
var init = Expression.MemberInit(createModel, bindings);

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Source, Dest>>(init, source);
```

Which will generate the following:

```
Param_0 => new Dest() 
{
    A = Param_0.get_A(), 
    B = Param_0.get_B()
}
```

And testing it:

```
var s = new Source { A = 5, B = "TEST" };
var res = lambdaExpression.Compile()(s);
```

Yields an object of `Dest`:

```
A    5   
B    TEST
```

Comment: LOL... yeah, this works... much easier then the way I was trying to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate the followup sections on generation, testing, and actual results, cheers